# the probability of that the winning combinations have at least two consecutive numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

> **suppose that we have a game in which there are 40 balls numbered 1 to 40 and six are drawn without replacement to determine the winning
> combination.we want to find the probability of  that the winning combinations have at least two consecutive numbers**

my attempt:

using numbers from 1 to 40,the number of  the possible pairs are ${40 \choose 2}$,from those pairs there is 39 pairs of consecutive numbers.

now let's take $B$ the set of all pairs of  consecutive numbers ,i.e B is the union of those 39 pairs.

$B=A_{1,2} \cup A_{2,3}\cup ......\cup A_{38,39} \cup A_{39,40}$ ($A_{i,j}$ is the pair $(i,j)$ where i and j are consecutive numbers)

let's calculate the probability of the event $B$  using "The Union of a Finite Number of Events" theorem

$P(B=A_{1,2} \cup A_{2,3}\cup ......\cup A_{38,39} \cup A_{39,40})=$

$\sum_{i=1}^{39}P(A_{i,i+1})-\sum_{}^{}P(A_{i,i+1} \cap A_{j,j+1})+\sum_{}^{}P(A_{i,i+1} \cap A_{j,j+1}\cap A_{w,w+1})+_-.....-P(A_{1,2} \cap A_{2,3}\cap .....\cap A_{39,40})$

**the first term $\sum_{i=1}^{39}P(A_{i,i+1})$**:the probability of each pair is just $\frac{1}{{40 \choose 2}}$,and we have 39 pairs so the first term equal $\frac{39}{{40 \choose 2}}$

**the Second term $\sum_{}^{}P(A_{i,i+1} \cap A_{j,j+1})=P(A_{1,2} \cap A_{2,3})+...$:** here in each term the first pair have the propability of   $\frac{1}{{40 \choose 2}}$ and the second pair have the propability of $\frac{1}{{40 \choose 2}-1}$ and we have ${39 \choose 2}$  terms,so the Second term equal $\frac{{39 \choose 2}}{({40 \choose 2}-1){40 \choose 2}}$.

i know that the attempt is not applicable because of such large amount of terms to deal with .anyway i have two questions:does  my approach is Right?,what is other approach to deal with this problem?.(i  started studying probability  in this  week  so please don't use advanced stuff )

Comment: The easiest way to do this problem is with complementary counting.  Subtract the probability that no two selected numbers are consecutive from $1$.

Comment: yeah,what do you think about my approach ,also does the first and second terms are good?

Comment: I do not think that you will move forward with this approach. It looks like a dead end. It is not even clear what is basically the "probability of a pair $P(A_{i,i+1})$". What is the *event* which probability should be described with this symbol?

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).
First, there are $\binom{40}6$ possible combinations.
Let the six balls in the winning combination be $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6$ where $a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4<a_5<a_6$.

Let $b_n=a_n-n+1$. We know that $1\le b_1\le b_2\le b_3\le b_4\le b_5\le b_6\le35$.
We also know that $b_x=b_{x+1}$ if and only if $a_x+1=a_{x+1}$.

There are $\binom{35}6$ possible combinations of b-values if they are required to be distinct. So there are $\binom{35}6$ possible combinations of a-values if no two a-values can be consecutive.
The final answer is $$1-\frac{\binom{35}6}{\binom{40}6}$$

Comment: I corrected it now.

Comment: Is it really "stars and bars"?

Comment: @Henry Could you clarify: what are here the stars and what are the bars?

Comment: If you prefer, it is just a combinatorial choice: $6$ from $40$ for the $a_i$ and $6$ from a manipulated $35$ for the $b_j$.  Stars and bars is a similar combinatorial choice

Comment: i did not understand the solution,also i still want to know if my approach is logically,and does the calculations of the first and second terms are fine

Comment: @Henry I agree that it is in some sense similar, but for me it is not classical "stars and bars".

Comment: @Magician In your place I would try to understand this very nice solution.

Comment: The starts and bars are 7 positive integers: $a_1,a_2-a_1-1,a_3-a_2-1,a_4-a_3-1,a_5-a_4-1,a_6-a_5-1,41-a_6$ which sum to 36. So there are 36 stars and 35 gaps between them. There are 7 positive integers so 6 bars are required in 6 different gaps.